# wp_redirect() not redirecting user to supplied URL

Tags: redirect

In my WordPress website I tried to log out user with `wp_logout()`, and redirect them to the login page with `wp_redirect()`; method. But wp_redirect() not redirecting user to supplied URL

**Logout and redirect code**:

```
wp_logout(); 
wp_redirect( 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php?loggedout=true' ); 
exit;
```

I tried to use wp_logout and wp_redirect hooks, they didn't work either

```
add_action ('wp_logout','logout_user');
        function logout_user()
        {
            wp_redirect( 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php?loggedout=true' );
            exit;
        }
            //get_header();
            wp_logout();
            exit;
```

Comment: Are you sure nothing else is being output beforehand? Redirects need to happen before the headers have been sent out, so if anything has been output already, it won't work and you'll get a PHP warning. Check your error logs

Comment: Yes. Nothing is being printed before. I made my repository public and you can access the file here https://github.com/pavankjadda/wordpress/blob/wordpress_login/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/index.php

Comment: That's not true, when I say nothing can be output i mean absolutely nothing of any kind, not just human visible stuff. I can see opening div containers and other output, or it to work it has to come before everything, including the `get_header` call, right at the top. The moment PHP sees even a single character, say ` ` a white space character, it sends out headers telling the browser to expect HTML, and your opportunity to send redirect headers is gone

Comment: Additionally, by the time that template is loaded, `template_redirect` has already happened. It needs to go inside your `functions.php` or a plugin. The order things run matters here. Also all your changes will get overwritten when twentyseventeen gets updated, you should move all of this into a child theme so that doesn't happen